# Django, Create GIN index for child element in JSON Array field

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model that uses PostgreSQL and has field like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    json_field = models.JSONField(default=list)
```

This field contains data like this:

```
[
  {"name": "AAAAA", "product": "11111"},
  {"name": "BBBBB", "product": "22222"},
]
```

Now I want to index by `json_field -> product` field, because it is being used as identification. Then i want to create `GinIndex` like this:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        GinIndex(name='product_json_idx', fields=['json_field->product'], opclasses=['jsonb_path_ops'])
    ]
```

When I try to create migration, I get error like this:

```
'indexes' refers to the nonexistent field 'json_field->product'.
```

How to create `GinIndex` that will be used for child attribute in Json Array?

Comment: Well, `json_field -> 'product'` won't return anything as the actual column value is an array. You would need `json_field @> '[{product: "11111"}]'` on the SQL level. And for that you need a GIN index on the column, not on an expression.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So django has nothing to help me to create that kind of index inside my project?

Comment: Please don't use a `JSONField`: relational databases are not good with such data: work with a junction model with a `ForeignKey` to the `Product`. Only if the structure is not fixed or unknown, you should use a `JSONField`.

Comment: I don't know django, but you do not need an index on an _expression_. You only need a (GIN) index on the _column_ itself. But Willem is right: using a properly normalized model is a much better approach to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please *don't* use a [**`JSONField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) for well-structured data: if the structure is clear, like here where we have a list of objects where each object has a name and a product, it makes more sense to work with extra models, like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class Entry(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This will automatically add indexes on the `ForeignKey`s, but will also make querying simpeler and usually more efficient.

While databases like PostgreSQL indeed have put effort into making JSON columns easier to query, aggregate, etc. usually it is still beter to perform [*database normalization* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), especially since it has more means for referential integrity, and a lot of aggregates are simpeler on *linear* data.

If for example later a product is removed, it will require a lot of work to inspect the JSON blobs to remove that product. This is however a scenario that both Django and PostgreSQL databases cover with ON DELETE triggers and which will likely be more effective and safe when using the Django toolchain for this.

Comment: sir willem, one thing i have to ask from you is while registering models in `admin.py`, does it requires `Admin` suffix, for example i have a model car, and i register it with `CarAdmin`, so it requires admin to be suffix, as `Form` and `View` requires?

Comment: @SunderamDubey: it is not required (the same for `Form` or `View`), but it is the convention yes.

Comment: ok, sir `willem`, it also seems convention to me, that's why we have a admin class `ModelAdmin` with admin suffix.